# Scrapy "ImportError" when running inside bash script

Tags: python, bash, shell, scrapy, python-import

I have a Python script (blah.py), where the first line is:

```
import scrapy
```

When I write "python blah.py" it works fine.

I have a .sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
python blah.py
```

When I execute the .sh script with "sh blah.sh" I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named scrapy
```

I can't figure out why. I want to execute it from within a .sh file because I am executing some other commands after the Python script.

Comment: maybe you are running it on a different environment, check in terminal when running `python blah.py` type `which python`, and the same inside the bash script, before the line of `python blah.py` type `which python`. Check if they are different.

Comment: You're right, they are different. Inside the script it was trying to use Python 2. From the terminal it uses Python 3. I changed the line in the script to "python3 blah.py" and now it works.

Comment: @elRuLL - I can accept your answer if you want to re-write your comment as an answer. The problem was that in .bashrc I had "python" as an alias for "/usr/local/bin/python3.5". But inside the bash script this alias is apparently not used.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, I'll add it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you could be running both on different environments.

Check in terminal when running  `python blah.py` which python version you are using with `which python`, and the same for the bash script, before the line of `python blah.py` type `which python`.

Make sure both paths are the same for them to work